# What is Cannon Time?

Tags: rise-of-nations

In Rise of Nations there is something called "Cannon Time" I've tried to find out what it means but haven't come across anything.

All I know is that it tries to activate when you hit the backspace button. What is Cannon Time?

Edit: What is it's use in RoN?

Answer (score 1):

Cannon time is bullet time but without the associated copyright infringements. It's essentially a toggle-able "slow motion" mode.

Comment: So what does it do in RON? - See Edit

Comment: You might add that it only applies to multiplayer. You can't use canon time in single player, nor do you need to, because in single player you can alter play-speed or pause the game at will.

Answer (score 0):

Because usually players pause the screen and make actions since RoN being a RTS, it is difficult to keep track of several things at once.
Slow motion mode essentially is like a pause and it is my view that the developers at RoN want us to use this mode instead of pausing because the game music resets everytime I pause whereas doesn't happen with this mode.